# Use truststore's SSLContext with Python requests Session object

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, truststore

Using the `truststore` library you can inject the context object universally, but in a recent update by the maintainers, it says you shouldn't do this.

How do you use the `truststore` with a requests.Session object?  I cannot seem to find guidance/doc on how to do this.  (it's probably me though)

Can someone please post a sample on using a `requests.Session` object with the `truststore` SSLContext?

reference: `https://truststore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#user-guide`
referenced PR: `https://github.com/sethmlarson/truststore/pull/122`